# How to seed the Firebase Storage Emulator?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to seed the Firebase Storage Emulator. I've added a json file to my project and I'm trying to upload this file to the Storage Emulator during the seed phase:

```
await firebaseAdmin
  .storage()
  .bucket()
  .upload(path.join('./data/cars.json'), {
    destination: `vehicles/cars.json`,
  });
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work and I'm running into the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Firebase Storage Emulator to work you need to initialize it in the Admin SDK:

```
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert('path/to/credential'),
  storageBucket: "bucket-name",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was by using `firebase-tools`

```
firebaseCli.emulators.start({
  project: "project-id",
  import: "path-to-file.json"
})
```

This will work only if the firebase emulator setup is done correctly and the data you are trying to import has the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Firebase CLI to start the emulators you can use the options `--export-on-exit=./data-dir` and `--import=./data-dir` as described here https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#startup

It looks like there's also an `emulators:export` command you could try.

> **--export-on-exit=**
>
> *Optional*. Use with the Authentication, Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database or Cloud Storage for Firebase emulator. Instruct the
> emulator(s) to export data to a directory when shutdown occurs, as
> described for the **emulators:export** command. The export directory
> can be specified with this flag: **firebase emulators:start
> --export-on-exit=./saved-data**. If **--import** is used, the export path defaults to the same; for example: **firebase emulators:start
> --import=./data-path --export-on-exit**. Lastly, if desired, pass different directory paths to the **--import** and **--export-on-exit**
> flags.
>
> **--import=import_directory**
>
> *Optional*. Use with the Authentication, Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database or Cloud Storage for Firebase emulator. Import data saved
> using the **--export-on-exit** startup option or the
> **emulators:export** command to a running Authentication, Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database or Cloud Storage for Firebase emulator
> instance. Any data currently in emulator memory will be overwitten.